dApp - Request Blocked - dApp May be malicious
Summary
I've been self-learning. and finally got my dApp Live after a few months.
However, I have done zero advertising because blowflish/phantom is telling user my site could be malicious.
Sure, the messages are not saying that it is explicitly malicious only that it could be, but then grey out the button to continue, and force users to click through three big red messages. No one would ever use that.
I spoke with both Phantom support and Blowfish, they expressed willingness to work with me, but they ask for things that just contradict cryptospace, and punish anyone not either well known or with an extensive history.
I'm a solo self-taught dev. from online materials that are open source, and education. All my dev work I've never uploaded to github, I don't have twitter/YouTube.
The Solana ecosystem is advertised as "developer friendly" and someone put in a ton of effort into building all the open-source documentation and guides. And they keep it updated.
So is the point being to waste developers time, money, and energy that want to advance their skill set and learn Solana, With the DENY EVERYONE but the "good ol boys club". is demoralizing to anyone that wants to become a developer etc.
They do say you can get someone to vouch for you, that is a highly popular/well known developer in the ecosystem. But who is going to do that for someone they don't know? With everything being open source, there has been no reason till now to try to join communities.
Bottom line, I'm at a dead end with blowflish because I don't have a big developer portfolio with historical documentation on github, with well-known socials etc. that I don't even want to currently have. Leaving me with only the vouch choice, but I have no idea where to begin on that.
I tried using the signAndSendTransaction since I saw on stack exchange that someone mentioned this method would not put your dApp on the "may be malicious" list.
I've lost hundreds of dollars perusing this, and countless hours of my time, and my families time over the last 6-9 months.
As a hail marry, is there anything that I'm missing, that phantom or anyone else could help me with? Only alternative I can think of is forcing my site to not allow phantom wallet due to gate keeping on the use of the wallet/wallet adapter.
Example
https://solanatokenfactory.com/
Steps to Reproduce
Step 1: Navigate to https://solanatokenfactory.com/
Step 2: Attach your wallet
Step 3: input your requested parameters to create a SPL Token.
Step 4: Click the Create Token button
Step 5: you will see the signature & Transaction Request in your wallet popup window which will have the 3 notifications for users.
